# Generationg a list from user-input dynamically

Tags: python, list, xrange

As the title says, I'm processing some command-line options to create a `list` from user input, like this: `"3,28,2"`. This is what I got so far:

```
>>> rR = "3,28,2"
>>> rR = re.split(r"[\W]+", rR)
>>> map(int, xrange( int(rR[0]),int(rR[1]),int(rR[2]) ))
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27]
>>>
```

FYI, the `re.split()` is because users are allowed to use comma (,) or space or both at the same time as the delimiter.

My question is how can I "automate" the `xrange(object)` bit so that user-input can be with or without start and step value (i.e. "*3,28,2*" vs. "*3,28*" vs. "*28*"). `len(rR)` does tell me the number of elements in the input but I'm kind of lost here with how can I use that information to write the xrange/range part dynamically.

Any idea(s)? Also trying to make my code as efficient as possible. So, any advise on that would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!!

Comment: I don't get why you apply `int` to `xrange`. Independently to your problem, why don't you just write `range(int(rR[0]),int(rR[1]),int(rR[2]))`?

Comment: @GuillaumeLemaître I don't understand that too, `xrange` is not useful when you need to convert it all to a list

Comment: I'm guessing he uses the `xrange` for something else, but used the `map(int` to display the result here, although `list()` would have been clearer

Comment: @GuillaumeLemaître: There are millions of numbers in the list and I didn't want to load the entire list into the memory, hence using xrange. It was just a cut-n-paste from the original script to show you guys what I'm after. But point noted. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> rR = "3,28,2"
>>> rR = re.split(r"[\W]+", rR)
>>> map(int, xrange(*map(int, rR)))
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27]
>>>
```

the * will unpack the elements into arguments for xrange.

Comment: @GP89: Didn't know that `*` trick; never ever thought it's gonna be that easy. thanks a lot. Only one prob is: you got one tailing `)` missing in the `map()`. Cheers!!

Comment: @MacUsers So i did! I've edited it now just for completeness :)

Answer (score 2):

```
In [46]: import re

In [47]: rR = "3,28,2"

In [48]: range(*map(int, re.split(r"\W+", rR)))
Out[48]: [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27]
```

References:

- [An explanation of the unpacking operator `*`](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/)
- [The official docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Comment: Very nice! Changing my original script wherever it's applicable. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer (list|generator) comprehensions to `map`.  I think they are considered more "pythonic", generally.

```
>>> rR = "3,28,2"
>>> range(*(int(x) for x in re.split(r"[\W]+", rR)))
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27]
```

Comment: Generally, however I think this is a case where `map` looks nicer